# Can Fabric run shell commands on a remote Windows machine?

Tags: python, fabric

I've been using Fabric on Linux systems for a while now and I've never had any issue with it. However, now I've branched out into Windows and I just cannot get anything to cooperate.

I've installed openSSHd on the remote Windows 8.1 system and I can send non-shell commands like `run('ipconfig', shell=False)` and such they will run as expected, but if I try the following.

```html
def runscripts_W():

 env.user = 'tester'
 env.password = 'password'
 env.cwd = 'C:/fabric_upload'  
 run('python runscripts.py')
```

I just get `Unable to execute command or shell on remote system: Failed to Execute Process`

I've tried installing MinGW and trying the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22504784/fabric-cannot-execute-remote-command-on-windows), but I am guessing Msys/MinGW can't work with Python 3.5 because even after editing the Msys fstab file with the python path I will just get back that the python command was not found and downgrading isn't an option.

Any one have any experience with Fabric on Windows? I know it isn't really meant for Windows, but it seems to be able to connect and send commands...I just need to get the machine to start up the python script. So close yet so far...

Comment: So, you want to run a python script on a remote windows machine? Is python there available? If not you could install IronPython there ([IronPython](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/))

Comment: Yes, python is installed on all remote machines, but will IronPython help invoke a normal python script? I thought that just let Python call .NET objects and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think I played out the Fabric options. I ended up going with Psexec launching the python script on the Windows machines. Though I was able to keep them contained to Fabric for launching purposes. I have the Psexec script in a bat file that launches via a Fabric local command. It isn't ideal, but it works at the added cost of two extra files in my directory with my fabfile; my bat file and psexec.exe.

Still rather aggravating that I can get so much to work on Windows via Fabric save for what I actually need.